# Flutter Creating instance from .fromJson fails (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int> in type cast')

Tags: flutter

**Short statement of the issue:**
I've an error while trying to convert a json string back to the object attributes.

**General info about the project**
I'm trying to build an Flutter (Version 3.3.5) App for Android. In the App, you can scan an EAN (barcode) and add the corresponding item to your shopping card. In this app I have 2 main models for the shopping part: Shoppingitem (code listed below) and Purchase, which essentually is just a List of ShoppingItems with some extra infos (code also listed below). I also use shared_preference for persisting my data (the current purchase).

**How i encounter the issue**

1. Converted a purchase instance to Json (String)
2. Wrote the string into a share_preference container
3. Read the string back
4. Tried to call the samplePurchase.fromJason(jsonString) <- Error

The problem occures when I want to fill an Purchase object with the Json data which was saved in my shared_preference. For filling the attributes of the object, I use the method Purchase.fromJson() which was automatically created by the Visual Studio Code extension "Dart Data Class Generator"

[image]

Shopping item class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ShoppingItem {
  final String ean;
  final String name;
  final double preisVorMwst;
  final double mwst;
  final String kategorie;
  double menge;

  ShoppingItem({
    required this.ean,
    required this.name,
    required this.preisVorMwst,
    required this.mwst,
    required this.kategorie,
    required this.menge,
  });

  void ChangeMenge(double newMenge)  {
    menge = newMenge;
  }

  ShoppingItem copyWith({
    String? ean,
    String? name,
    double? preisVorMwst,
    double? mwst,
    String? kategorie,
    double? menge,
  }) {
    return ShoppingItem(
      ean: ean ?? this.ean,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      preisVorMwst: preisVorMwst ?? this.preisVorMwst,
      mwst: mwst ?? this.mwst,
      kategorie: kategorie ?? this.kategorie,
      menge: menge ?? this.menge,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'ean': ean,
      'name': name,
      'preisVorMwst': preisVorMwst,
      'mwst': mwst,
      'kategorie': kategorie,
      'menge': menge,
    };
  }

  factory ShoppingItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ShoppingItem(
      ean: map['ean'] as String,
      name: map['name'] as String,
      preisVorMwst: map['preisVorMwst'] as double,
      mwst: map['mwst'] as double,
      kategorie: map['kategorie'] as String,
      menge: map['menge'] as double,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ShoppingItem.fromJson(String source) => ShoppingItem.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ShoppingItem(ean: $ean, name: $name, preisVorMwst: $preisVorMwst, mwst: $mwst, kategorie: $kategorie, menge: $menge)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant ShoppingItem other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      other.ean == ean &&
      other.name == name &&
      other.preisVorMwst == preisVorMwst &&
      other.mwst == mwst &&
      other.kategorie == kategorie &&
      other.menge == menge;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return ean.hashCode ^
      name.hashCode ^
      preisVorMwst.hashCode ^
      mwst.hashCode ^
      kategorie.hashCode ^
      menge.hashCode;
  }
}
```

Purchase class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:customerfe/service/ServiceFactory.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/models/item.dart';

class Purchase {
  final String user;
  DateTime date;
  double finalPrice;
  List<ShoppingItem> items;

  Purchase({
    required this.user,
    required this.date,
    required this.finalPrice,
    required this.items,
  });
  
  void AddItemWithItemInput(ShoppingItem itemIn)  {
    items.add(itemIn);
  }

  void AddItemWithStringInput(String _ean, String _name, double _preisVorMwst, double _mwst, String _kategorie, double _menge)  {
    ShoppingItem itemIn = ShoppingItem(ean: _ean, name: _name, preisVorMwst: _preisVorMwst, mwst: _mwst, kategorie: _kategorie, menge: _menge);
    items.add(itemIn);
  }

  int Getlength()  {
    return items.length;
  }

  void AddItemWithEan(String _ean)  {
    items.add(ServiceFactory().GetItemAttributes(_ean));
  }

  void DeleteItem()  {
    // TODO Write Delete Item Methode
  }

  void UpdateItem()  {
    // TODO Write Update Item Methode
  }

  Purchase copyWith({
    String? user,
    DateTime? date,
    double? finalPrice,
    List<ShoppingItem>? items,
  }) {
    return Purchase(
      user: user ?? this.user,
      date: date ?? this.date,
      finalPrice: finalPrice ?? this.finalPrice,
      items: items ?? this.items,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'user': user,
      'date': date.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'finalPrice': finalPrice,
      'items': items.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory Purchase.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Purchase(
      user: map['user'] as String,
      date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['date'] as int),
      finalPrice: map['finalPrice'] as double,
      items: List<ShoppingItem>.from((map['items'] as List<int>).map<ShoppingItem>((x) => ShoppingItem.fromMap(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Purchase.fromJson(String source) => Purchase.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Purchase(user: $user, date: $date, finalPrice: $finalPrice, items: $items)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Purchase other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
  
    return 
      other.user == user &&
      other.date == date &&
      other.finalPrice == finalPrice &&
      listEquals(other.items, items);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return user.hashCode ^
      date.hashCode ^
      finalPrice.hashCode ^
      items.hashCode;
  }
}
```

Factory class for handling the reading/writing of data

```
import 'package:customerfe/models/history.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/service/SharedPreference.dart';

import '../models/purchase.dart';

class PersistFactory {


  static Future loginProcess(String username) async  {
    String oldUser = await SharedPreference.getUsername();
    if(username == oldUser)  {
      return Future;
      //await SharedPreference.setUsername(username);
    } else {
      //Different Username -> Old Purchase and History has to be deleted
      await SharedPreference.setUsername(username);
      SharedPreference.emptyHistory();
      SharedPreference.emptyPurchase();
    }
  }
  
  static String getUsername()  {
    return SharedPreference.getUsername();
  }

  static Future setPurchase(Purchase einkauf)  {
    return SharedPreference.setPurchase(einkauf);
  }

  static String getPurchaseAsJason()  {
    return SharedPreference.getPurchase();
  }

  static Future setHistory(History einkauefe)  {
    return SharedPreference.setHistory(einkauefe);
  }

  static String getHistoryAsJson()  {
    return SharedPreference.getHistory();
  }
}
```

Class for shared_preference

```
import 'package:customerfe/models/history.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/models/item.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/models/purchase.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SharedPreference  {

  static late SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static const _keyUsername = 'username';
  static const _keyPurchase = 'purchase';
  static const _keyHistory = 'history';

  static Future init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static Future setUsername(String username) async {
    await _preferences.setString(_keyUsername, username);
  }

  static String getUsername() { 
    String? tempNull;
    tempNull = _preferences.getString(_keyUsername);
    if(tempNull == null)  {
      return "Data was null";
    } else {
      return tempNull;
    }
  }

  static void emptyUsername()  {
    _preferences.setString(_keyUsername, "");
  }

  static Future setPurchase(Purchase einkauf) async {
    await _preferences.setString(_keyPurchase, einkauf.toJson());
  }

  static String getPurchase() { 
    if(_preferences.getString(_keyPurchase) == "" || _preferences.getString(_keyPurchase) == null)  {
      return Purchase(date: DateTime.now(), user: getUsername(), finalPrice: 0, items:[
        ShoppingItem(ean: "Miep", name: "Miep", preisVorMwst: 17, mwst: 17, kategorie: "Kat", menge: 2)
      ]).toJson();
    }
    String? tempNull;
    tempNull = _preferences.getString(_keyPurchase);
    if(tempNull == null)  {
      return "";
    } else {
      return tempNull;
    }
  }

  static void emptyPurchase()  {
    _preferences.setString(_keyPurchase, "");
  }

  static Future setHistory(History history) async  {
    await _preferences.setString(_keyHistory, history.toJson());
  }

  static String getHistory()  {
    String? tempNull;
    tempNull = _preferences.getString(_keyHistory);
    if(tempNull == null)  {
      return "";
    } else {
      return tempNull;
    }
  }

  static void emptyHistory()  {
    _preferences.setString(_keyHistory, "");
  }

}
```

Screen where i call the function

```
import 'package:customerfe/models/purchase.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/screens/history.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/screens/shopping.dart';
import 'package:customerfe/service/PersistFactory.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../config.dart';
import '../models/item.dart';

class MainNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainNavigator({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainNavigator> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<MainNavigator> {

  List<ShoppingItem> initional = [
    ShoppingItem(ean: "Miep", name: "Probe", preisVorMwst: 12, mwst: 17, kategorie: "Test", menge: 3),
  ];

  String title = "";
  int currentIndex=0;

  PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  String out = PersistFactory.getPurchaseAsJason();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(currentIndex==0)  {
      title="Einkaufen";
    }
    if(currentIndex==1)  {
      title="Historie";
    }

    return Configuration(
      ShoppingList: 
      
      //Purchase(user: PersistFactory.getUsername(), date: DateTime.now(), finalPrice: 0, items: []),


     Purchase.fromJson(PersistFactory.getPurchaseAsJason()), <- Problem
      child: 
    
    Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title),
      actions: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Icon(Icons.logout),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
            },
          ),
        )
      ],),
      body: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex=value;
          });
        },
        children: [
          ShoppingScreen(),
          HistoryScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "Einkaufen"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "Historie"),
        ],
        onTap: (value) {
          pageController.animateToPage(value, duration: Duration(microseconds: 100), curve: Curves.ease);
        },
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

From my understanding, the automatically created method fromJson() or the fromMap() has an error regarding the data types. I had the idea to make my own format of writing and reading data but I need to created Purchase items from and Rest API later in the project. Therefore the fromJson has to work for me :(.

Thank you for your help

Concluded that the automatically created methods are the issue, by using different methods.

Comment: Share your JSON response for better understanding of problem

Comment: {"user":"dev","date":1668159963095,"finalPrice":8.18,"items":[{"ean":"","name":"ExampleItem","preisVorMwst":6.99,"mwst":0.17,"kategorie":"Meat","menge":1.0}]}

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using to generate factory fromJson toJson?
I think the problem is in `Purchase` class.

```
factory Purchase.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Purchase(
      user: map['user'] as String,
      date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['date'] as int),
      finalPrice: map['finalPrice'] as double,
      items: List<ShoppingItem>.from((map['items'] as List<int>).map<ShoppingItem>((x) => ShoppingItem.fromMap(x as Map<String,dynamic>),),),
    );
  }
```

`map['items'] as List<int>` should be  `as List<dynamic>`

```
factory Purchase.FromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Purchase(
      user: json['user'] as String,
      date: DateTime.parse(json['date'] as String),
      finalPrice: (json['finalPrice'] as num).toDouble(),
      items: (json['items'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map((e) => ShoppingItem.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList(),
    )
```

Comment: Solution threw an error for me: "The argument type 'Map<String, dynamics>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" at the .map((e) method